# TFS 2010 - TF215097 .Cannot create unknown type '{clr-namespace:

Tags: namespaces, workflow

On TFS 2010, I have this mistake when I launch my Build Definition containing my custom activity:

```
TF215097: An error occurred while initializing a build for build definition \BCA3\BuildProcessSourcet8: Cannot create unknown type '{clr-namespace:BuildProcessSourcet8.Activities;assembly=Sourcet8}CopyActivity'.
```

Part of XAML file:

```
<Activity mc:Ignorable="sads sap sap2010" x:Class="TfsBuild.Process" this:Process.AutomatedTests="[{ New Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Common.BuildParameter(&quot; { &quot;&quot;AssemblyFileSpec&quot;&quot;: &quot;&quot;**\\*test*.dll;**\\*test*.appx&quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;RunSettingsFileName&quot;&quot;: null, &quot;&quot;TestCaseFilter&quot;&quot;: &quot;&quot;&quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;RunSettingsForTestRun&quot;&quot;: { &quot;&quot;ServerRunSettingsFile&quot;&quot;: &quot;&quot;&quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;TypeRunSettings&quot;&quot;: &quot;&quot;Default&quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;HasRunSettingsFile&quot;&quot;: false }, &quot;&quot;HasRunSettingsFile&quot;&quot;: false, &quot;&quot;HasTestCaseFilter&quot;&quot;: false, &quot;&quot;ExecutionPlatform&quot;&quot;: &quot;&quot;X86&quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;FailBuildOnFailure&quot;&quot;: false, &quot;&quot;RunName&quot;&quot;: &quot;&quot;&quot;&quot; } &quot;) }]" this:Process.AdvancedTestSettings="[New Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Common.BuildParameter(&quot; { &quot;&quot;AnalyzeTestImpact&quot;&quot;: false, &quot;&quot;DisableTests&quot;&quot;: false, &quot;&quot;PreActionScriptPath&quot;&quot;: &quot;&quot;&quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;PreActionScriptArguments&quot;&quot;: &quot;&quot;&quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;PostActionScriptPath&quot;&quot;: &quot;&quot;&quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;PostActionScriptArguments&quot;&quot;: &quot;&quot;&quot;&quot; } &quot;)]" this:Process.BuildNumberFormat="[&quot;$(BuildDefinitionName)_$(Date:yyyyMMdd)$(Rev:.r)&quot;]" this:Process.CleanWorkspace="[True]" this:Process.CreateLabel="[True]" this:Process.AdvancedBuildSettings="[New Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Common.BuildParameter(&quot; { &quot;&quot;MSBuildArguments&quot;&quot;: &quot;&quot;&quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;MSBuildPlatform&quot;&quot;: &quot;&quot;Auto&quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;PreActionScriptPath&quot;&quot;: &quot;&quot;&quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;PreActionScriptArguments&quot;&quot;: &quot;&quot;&quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;PostActionScriptPath&quot;&quot;: &quot;&quot;&quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;PostActionScriptArguments&quot;&quot;: &quot;&quot;&quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;RunCodeAnalysis&quot;&quot;: &quot;&quot;AsConfigured&quot;&quot; } &quot;)]" this:Process.AgentSettings="[New Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Common.BuildParameter(&quot; { &quot;&quot;MaxExecutionTime&quot;&quot;: &quot;&quot;00:00:00&quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;MaxWaitTime&quot;&quot;: &quot;&quot;04:00:00&quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;Name&quot;&quot;: &quot;&quot;*&quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;Tags&quot;&quot;: [], &quot;&quot;TagComparison&quot;&quot;: &quot;&quot;MatchExactly&quot;&quot; } &quot;)]" this:Process.CleanBuild="[True]" this:Process.OutputLocation="[&quot;SingleFolder&quot;]" this:Process.CreateWorkItem="[True]" this:Process.UpdateAssociatedWorkItems="[True]" this:Process.SupportedReasons="All" this:Process.BuildProcessVersion="12.0"
 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2009/xaml/activities"
 xmlns:local="clr-namespace:BuildProcessSourcet8;assembly=Sourcet8"
 xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
 xmlns:mtba="clr-namespace:Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Activities;assembly=Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Activities"
 xmlns:mtbac="clr-namespace:Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Activities.Core;assembly=Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Activities"
 xmlns:mtbat="clr-namespace:Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Activities.TeamFoundation;assembly=Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Activities"
 xmlns:mtbc="clr-namespace:Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Common;assembly=Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Common"
 xmlns:mtbc1="clr-namespace:Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client;assembly=Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client"
 xmlns:mtbw="clr-namespace:Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow;assembly=Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow"
 xmlns:mtbwa="clr-namespace:Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.Activities;assembly=Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow"
 xmlns:mtbwt="clr-namespace:Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.Tracking;assembly=Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow"
 xmlns:mva="clr-namespace:Microsoft.VisualBasic.Activities;assembly=System.Activities"
 xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
 xmlns:sads="http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2010/xaml/activities/debugger"
 xmlns:sap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2009/xaml/activities/presentation"
 xmlns:sap2010="http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2010/xaml/activities/presentation"
 xmlns:scg="clr-namespace:System.Collections.Generic;assembly=mscorlib"
 xmlns:sco="clr-namespace:System.Collections.ObjectModel;assembly=mscorlib"
 xmlns:this="clr-namespace:TfsBuild"
 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
```

- My Build controller is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution seems to put the custom activity DLL in the GAC.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by installing same version of VisualStudio and TFS client in the build machine. For example Install VS 2013 and TFS 2013 and also make sure you build the custom dll also using the VS 2013 .